# странная ошибка в DDL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner = "Foo owner";
```

Этот запрос почему-то генерирует ошибку:

> invalid identifier *Foo owner* found.

Что это это за бред? почему константная строка вдруг стала неверной!?
Поставил одинарные кавычки и все заработало. Что за бред.

Comment: Вы в mysql видели запросы, там часто имена колонок заключают в обратные апострофы. В ms sql имена колонок заключают в квадратные скобки. А в oracle для этой цели используют двойные кавычки. Для задания текстовых констант используют исключительно одинарные кавычки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так правильно:

```
select table_name from all_tables where owner = 'Foo owner';
```

Строки обрамляются одной кавычкой. В данном случае Oracle ищет колонку с именем `"Foo owner"`

Comment: а если я захочу сравнить именно с константной строкой

Comment: Строка обрамляется одинарными ковычками. `'Foo'` строка, `"Foo"` имя колонки или таблицы или еще чего нибудь

Comment: @voipp Я так понял, что вам указали на то, что для поиска константного строкового литерала стоит воспользоваться записью вида `where varChar2FieldName = 'SomeString';` причем следующая запись будет аналогична предыдущей `where "varChar2FieldName" = 'SomeString';`

Comment: @StateItPrimitive да, мне нужна константная строка. А одинарные кавычки - не константа. Константа - это двойные.

Comment: Мы сейчас говорим об Oracle sql ? Если да, то я не понимаю, что такое константная и не константная строка в данном контексте. Если мы говорим еще о чем то, то поясните, о чем вообще мы говорим

Comment: @voipp Что-то я вас не совсем понимаю, так ведь такая строка (`'SomeString'`) в этом контексте явно будет константной (мы же не можем её поменять). Просто в PL/SQL ведь все строки пишутся в одинарных кавычках, а в двойные лишь заключаются имена полей, например, что необходимо для случаев, когда наименование поля содержит пробел, например.